# How do I adjust the map rotation on my Source-based game server?

Tags: server-administration, source-engine

For Source-based games (Counter Strike: Source, Team Fortress 2, Left For Dead), how do I change the map rotation on my own server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to go into the `cstrike` or `tf` folder and create/edit the mapcycle.txt file.

Simply make a list of maps separated by newlines.

Note: You can't have L4D have a mapcycle because the campaign is decided by the people that will play on your server.